# Apache dies, and never listens or repsonds again even after a reboot?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, debian-lenny

This is very strange! Running debian Lenny 32bit. Have Apache/MySql 5.5.15/Mongo and Memcached running on a dev machine. This is the second time this happened after running a complex query in Mysql. The first time Mongo was involved so I know that is not the culprit now. This time I terminated the query, and apache2 is permanently down for the kill. I stopped every process on the machine, and restarted all of them, but I can't access the server. Apache set up on a higher port with ssl. Even rebooting does not do the trick!!

Someone fixed the server once but I can't seem to find them...long story.

Tried accessing the site thru local lynx - got unable to connect with remote host. Obviously apache is running....

```
root      3277  0.0  0.8  66932  8816 ?  Ss   19:30   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start 
www-data  3283  0.0  0.4  66932  4408 ?  S    19:30   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start 
www-data  3284  0.0  0.4  66932  4408 ?  S    19:30   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  3285  0.0  0.4  66932  4408 ?  S    19:30   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start 
www-data  3286  0.0  0.4  66932  4408 ?  S    19:30   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start 
www-data  3287  0.0  0.4  66932  4408 ?  S    19:30   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Comment: Did you try a netstat -apn, so you can see what's listening on your ports, what does the apache logs say ?

Comment: [Sat Aug 13 20:42:37 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Aug 13 20:42:38 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: Also netstat shows httpd running     0 xxx.xxx.xx.x:23492     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2921/apache2

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it has to do with the router(well all in one firewall/router/wireless Motorola SBG 900) on my end blocking the box and port after excessive activity. I was able to reproduce the problem and watch it end up in my router log. All the machines here are on 1 IP and go thru the router so it was a bit tricky to resolve. I will always pull up my firewall log now with any weird network issues and I configured it to send email alerts.

---

DISCLAIMER: The original poster updated their original question with this answer, so I'm posting this as a community wiki answer to fit the Q&A format of the site.

This answer is not mine and was copied and pasted verbatim from the question, and as such I take no credit for it.